# Will taking the top off my vessel on day 9 spoil my brew?

Tags: fermentation, contamination

I’m on day 9 of my home brew and the top has been taken off for about 5 seconds. Reading up on the CO2 layer that the yeast creates in wort and that exposure to oxygen can spoil your beer, I fear my batch might be in jeopardy.

Anyone have some knowledge or experience on this issue? Or done so in the past?

Any advice would ease my mind.

Comment: Don't worry. After that time fermentation is probably already done. The beer has now alcohol and a low ph, neither of which make it easy for other organisms to get a hold. The hops help to preverve as well. Finally there's nothing more to eat for wild yeasts, and the beer yeast already has a strong foothold.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Six seconds is nothing. I do open fermentation for a couple of days, then rack my beer into a closed fermenter after four days. For this I need to expose my beer for more than a couple of seconds. I get fine beer.

Work clean and minimise exposition, but do not worry too much. Beer is more resilient than people usually think.

Comment: No worries, as chthon mentionned, keep your instruments clean and sanitized, other than that, you'll be fine.

Comment: Thank you,  I’m Day 11 at wort.  Testing gravity and tasting every couple days.  It tasted about right on day 8 and after the top incident had some after taste and thought It was ruined.  Last few days it’s eased on the after taste so think it’s heading in the right direction.  Going to let it stay at wort until tastes right.